# Efficiently Parsing XSD with xmlschema, without XML Available

Tags: python, xsd

```
import xmlschema
data_schema = xmlschema.XMLSchema("myXSD.xsd")
data = data_schema.to_dict("myXSD.xsd")
```

I am not sure what the normal use case for this is, but I only have a ton of XSD files to parse, so I ended up passing the XSD file into both of these calls to get a dictionary.  Now that I am basically done, I am focusing on how slow it is, requiring nearly a 10 second delay between launching the script and the GUI being usable because all of this information is required to populate it.

Profiling the script, I saw that most of the time is from the initial read and then the second largest part was populating the dictionary.  Since I am not actually passing an .xml file like documentation says the second call should be doing, I assume it is failing the process when reading the .xsd a second time but still giving me the desired dictionary.

Is there any way to get the dictionary without it reading the same file two times?  I have tried passing other things, including `None`, but that does not work.

Comment: What data are you expecting in the dictionary? I looks like you are parsing the schema into the dictionary… Are you building your UI from the schema?

Comment: Building the UI with the schema, but not from it.  Basically there are some variable length fields and whatnot between sets of XSD files so there might be an extra check box in one area for one set of files.

Comment: You could to parse your schema once into an ElementTree e.g. `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` and `schema1 = ET.parse('myXSD.xsd')` and then to reuse that ElementTree in e.g. `data_schema = xmlschema.XMLSchema(schema1)` and `data = data_schema.to_dict(schema1)`. I don't know whether that performs any better.